# UnsupportedOperationException в setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, исключения

Вылетает UnsupportedOperationException. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем проблема? Может ли это быть связано с тем, что создаю массив, у которого фиксированный размер?
Заранее спасибо и всем хороших выходных!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT = "text";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_QUANTITY = "quantity";

    ListView lvSimple;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String[] texts = {Util.text1, Util.text2, Util.text3, Util.text4,
                Util.text5, Util.text6, Util.text7, Util.text8 };

        int[] quantity2 = {texts[0].length(), texts[1].length(), texts[2].length(),
                texts[3].length(), texts[4].length(), texts[5].length(), texts[6].length() , texts[7].length()};

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                texts.length);
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, texts[i]);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_QUANTITY, quantity2[i]);
            data.add(m);
        }

        String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_QUANTITY};
        int[] to = { R.id.tvText, R.id.tvText2 };

        final SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item,
                from, to);

        lvSimple = findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);
        lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);

        lvSimple.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                lvSimple.getItemAtPosition(position);
                lvSimple.removeViewAt(position);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UnsupportedOperationException**

Часто эта ошибка возникает, когда мы используем метод `asList()` из `java.util.Arrays:`

```
public static List asList(T... a)
```

Возвращает:
фиксированный размер `List` от размера данного `array` 
элемент того же типа, что и в оригинальном array , и это
должен быть `Object` элементы в том же порядке как в исходном массиве
список, который `Serializable` и реализует RandomAccess

Поскольку `T` является ссылкой:`/java-varargs[ varargs ]`, мы можем передать массив или элементы непосредственно в качестве параметров, и метод создаст инициализированный список фиксированного размера:

```
List<String> flowers = Arrays.asList("Ageratum", "Allium", "Poppy", "Catmint");
```

Мы также можем передать фактический `array` :

```
String[]flowers = { "Ageratum", "Allium", "Poppy", "Catmint" };
List<String> flowerList = Arrays.asList(flowers);
```

Поскольку возвращенный List является List фиксированного размера, мы не можем добавлять/удалять элементы.

Попытка добавить больше элементов вызовет UnsupportedOperationException:

```
String[]flowers = { "Ageratum", "Allium", "Poppy", "Catmint" };
List<String> flowerList = Arrays.asList(flowers);
flowerList.add("Celosia");
```

Корень этого Exception заключается в том, что возвращаемый объект не реализует операцию `_add()` , поскольку он не совпадает `с java.util.ArrayList._`

Это `ArrayList` , из `java.util.Arrays`.

Другой способ получить то же исключение - попытаться удалить элемент из полученного списка.

С другой стороны, есть способы получить изменяемый `List` на тот случай, если он нам понадобится.

Одним из них является создание `ArrayList` или любого вида списка непосредственно из результата `asList()` :

```
String[]flowers = { "Ageratum", "Allium", "Poppy", "Catmint" };
List<String> flowerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(flowers));
```

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе следует указывать какая строка выбивает ошибку. Подозреваю что эта:

```
lvSimple.removeViewAt(position);
```

потому что в `ListView` нельзя управлять элементами напрямую в обход адаптера. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView#removeViewAt(int)
Вместо этого нужно изменить коллекцию данных, связанную с адаптером и уведомить адаптер об изменении, чтобы он обновил вывод на экране.
В данном примере это нужно делать так:

```
    lvSimple.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            data.remove(position);
            sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```